# Gradle Native C project: Header file not getting included from another header file with relative path

Tags: c, gradle, compilation

I am trying to integrate a 3rd party SDK(written in c), into my native C Gradle application. I am running into issues with `#includes` from inside other headers in the SDK.

If I compile using the eclipse build tools everything compiles nicely

However when I moved over everything to Gradle (due to flexibility with other steps in the build)... I cant figure out why the .h files referenced from another .h aren't found. ( Note this is being built by parent project)

All the paths in the SDK are relative to the root of the SDK

It was my understanding that all the header files would be specified in the following script block

```
exportedHeaders {
        srcDirs  { <headers in here> }
}
```

I have the following directory structure

```
/ts3
  /include
  /lib
      /include
           /teamlog
               - logtypes.h
           /teamspeak
               - public_definitions.h
  /src
     -HelloWorld
```

---

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'c'
    model {
        platforms {
         x64 {
            architecture "x86_64"
             }
        }

        components {
            tada(NativeLibrarySpec){
                 targetPlatform "x64"
                  sources {
                     c {
                        source {            
                            srcDirs "src"
                            include "*.c"
                        }
                         exportedHeaders {
                           srcDirs  "include",
                                "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_162\\include",
                                "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_162\\include\\win32",
                                "lib\\ts3_sdk_3.0.4\\include\\teamspeak"            
                       }            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After compiling on Windows 10, I get the following error

```
ts3\lib\ts3_sdk_3.0.4\include\teamspeak\public_definitions.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../../../../ts3_sdk_3.0.4/include/teamlog/logtypes.h': No such file or directory
```